# upgraded from ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 and now Nautilus crashes video driver

Tags: 14.04, drivers, 16.04, nvidia, nautilus

I upgraded my desktop from Ubuntu 14.04LTS to 16.04LTS x64. The upgrade went smooth, but for some reason whenever I load Nautilus, the video driver will crash.

Let me provide a bit more detail. I have two monitors and I use the i3 windows manager. When I execute the command to load the Nautilus file manager, the wallpaper image on the left monitor will blink for a second and then the image spills over into the status bar at the bottom of the screen. On the right monitor, the wallpaper get a strange line right down the middle, and half the image covers the status bar and the other half does not.

So obviously something strange is happening to the video. I tried reinstalling and upgrading the nvidia drivers. I have a GeForce 650Ti video card, and I upgraded the drivers to Nvidia 370.28, which should work according to the nvidia site.

Any suggestions on what else I can do to fix this? Would the "nomodetest" setting change anything? I have not noticed this issue when loading any other application.

Comment: nomodeset forces a generic VESA video driver instead. Its use is only in those cases where a particular Nvidia chipset (and others)  isn't correctly supported (no video) with the default open-source driver, so you have video during installation and until you install the proprietary drivers. So no, nothing to do with your case, not a solution.